# Write to a File using CsvHelper in C#

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I tried to write to CSV file using CsvHelper in C#.
This is the link to the library http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

I used the code in web site.

Here is my code:

```
var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
foreach (var value in valuess)
{
    csv.WriteRecord(value);
}
```

It writes only a part of data to csv file.
Last rows were missing.
Could you please help with this.

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? Especially the declaration of `writer` is interesting.

Comment: when, I added this code after the loop code is working well

    writer.Close();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when, I added this code after the loop code is working well

```
var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
foreach (var value in valuess)
{
     csv.WriteRecord(value);
}
writer.Close();
```

The problem occurred because I did not close the Connection

Comment: You should Dispose your writer, "using" is a good pratice
`using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filepath)) { ... }`

Comment: Starting from CSVHelper 13.0.0
There are breaking change in Factory.CreateWriter
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log

Comment: And for ANSI  - Windows-1252?

Answer (score 44):

You need to flush the stream. The Using statement will flush when out of scope.

```
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.csv", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    var csv = new CsvWriter(writer);
    csv.WriteRecords(values); // where values implements IEnumerable
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that `writer` is some kind of TextWriter, you should add a call to flush the contents before closing the writer:

```
writer.Flush()
```

If the last lines are missing, this is the most likely reason.

Comment: when, I added this code after the loop code is working well

    writer.Close();

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @greg's answer:

```
using (var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\out.csv", false, Encoding.UTF8)) {
  using (var csv = new CsvWriter(sr)) {
    csv.WriteRecords(values);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
          {
              Delimiter = Delimiter
          };
using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, configuration))
{
    csvWriter.WriteRecords(itemsData);
    csvWriter.Flush();
}

//This is an example that might help you
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add an explanation of your answer.